# Projects and Beacon Ownership rules changed?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform, google-proximity-api

Last time I worked with `Nearby` and `Proximity` API as on July of this year, and, according to the [docs (last update Fev. 2017)](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/projects-and-ownership):

> Any beacon you register with the Proximity Beacon API is associated
>   only with the project under which it was registered. Once registered
>   with a project, the only way to move a beacon to another project is to
>   give the beacon hardware a new beacon ID using the provisioning
>   software from the beacon manufacturer, and then register the beacon
>   with the new project.

If I remember correctly when a beacon was added to the Beacon Dashboard it was possible to add attachments only to the project where the beacon was added. I could configure a namespace, type and data.

Today I had to configure another project and for my surprise when I was in the attachment tab I could choose a different project to add that attachment and the namespace is not editable anymore (is given by default and it's similar to the project id).

Does this mean I can have a "My beacons global project" and then configure attachments to other projects? I've made a test and the attachments where delivered to other projects as configured.

Did something change in the meanwhile or I've always missed this from the beginning?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Attachment visibility](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/attachments#attachment_visibility)

> By default, your project's namespace visibility is set to UNLISTED, so
>   its attachments are served only to your project, not to other
>   developers' projects.
>
> A single beacon can support multiple attachments in different
>   namespaces, added by different projects using the Proximity Beacon
>   API's IAM roles. Each project controls the visibility of its
>   namespace, so it is possible for a single beacon to support a mixture
>   of public and unlisted attachments.